# values:dimens.xml - error: resource android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private

Tags: android

A friend is working on and app (here's [the link](https://github.com/anta40/notesx), it's a fork of [this project](https://github.com/vishesh/sealnote)). He said that he can build the project on his PC.
But when I tried to build it, I go this error:

> error: resource android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource
>   android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private.,
>   sources=[C:\Users\Phincon\AndroidStudioProjects\notesx-master\NotesX\src\main\res\values\dimens.xml:9:5-58],
>   original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Looks like this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865366/cardslib-error-resource-androidattr-foregroundinsidepadding-is-private-while-ta) similar to my problem. I couldn't find any occurence of **android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding**. I'm using Android Studio 3.1.3, compile SDK is 25, build tools version is 27, Gradle 3.1.3. Minimum SDK is 14, and target SDK is 25.

This is confusing. Is there any workaround? THank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That value is an Android System resource attribute. You should not be using it. OEMs (such as Samsung/LG/Htc etc..) have free reign to change these values, as they are private system values.

Its possible that an Android Studio or Android SDK update is now enforcing this and preventing you from using that value. Either way, the tooling is correct and you should not be depending on that resource.

Comment: OK, after some careful inspections, in my dimens.xml, there are some Android resource attributes (Android Studio highlighted them). Guess I have to rename all of them manually.

Comment: Yup. If this answer was helpful and/or correct please mark it as such for future reference. Have a great day!