# Cardslib old library android studio

Tags: android, cardslib

I need to run an old Android Studio project; this project relies too much on this library(Cardslib).

But when trying to compile the project with the library cardslib, it throws this error:'resource  android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private`. Following this answer, [https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241073/22742641](https://stackoverflow.com)  I try to modify the repositorie, but when compiling, I get an endless amount of errors. Then I look at the repositorie and find this discussion https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/issues/568#issuecomment-761879506 It did help me find the files I needed to modify, but still I cannot compile cardslib. Does anyone have encountered this problem with cardslib and can explain their solution? Please. Sorry but I am new to android development.